# Linux Shell Script: How to compare a specific field in a text document with specific text in an if statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, string-comparison

I have a file named transfer.log that has a few Apache logs.  I need to count how many GET requests each IP address has logged.  I know how to access the file and loop through the lines in the file but I am having trouble with comparing the 6th field in each line with "GET".

```
#!/bin/bash    

while read p; 
do
    name=( $(awk '{print $6}' p))
    echo $name
    if [ "$name" == "GET" ]
    then
            echo "yes"
    else
        echo "no"
    fi
done < transfer.log
```

Currently, when I run the script "no" is printed 5 times and I receive an error that says awk cannot open the file "p".  When I change the p to transfer.log in the variable declaration, I can get the echo $name to output "GET (with the quotation), but it obviously never changes because it is accessing the entire file and not the new line p.

I need to know how to assign the 6th column of p to my variable name each time the while loop executes.  Also, I am confused as to why my loop only iterates 5 times and not 6.

My transfer.log looks like this:

```
140.211.167.27 - - [15/Oct/2012:23:11:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2963 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
140.211.167.27 - - [15/Oct/2012:23:11:46 +0000] "GET /systems/ganeti/index HTTP/1.1" 200 5918 "https://wiki.osuosl.org/systems/index" "Mozilla/5.0(X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
140.211.167.9 - - [15/Oct/2012:23:17:33 +0000] "GET /resources/index HTTP/1.1" 200 3411 "https://wiki.osuosl.org/index" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
140.211.167.25 - - [15/Oct/2012:16:02:07 +0000] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 2673 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
66.249.74.101 - - [15/Oct/2012:02:20:14 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 2458 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
128.193.164.34 - - [15/Oct/2012:12:41:18 +0000] "POST /rpc/xmlrpc HTTP/1.0" 200 8328 "-" "PHP XMLRPC 1.0"
```

**Ultimately, I need to count how many GET requests each specific IP address has logged and sort the addresses by least to greatest GET requests.**

Comment: Your 6th field extracted by `awk` will contain the value `"GET` and not `GET`!!! that's why you have issues in the string evaluation and actually you do not need to create a whole shell script for this pure `awk` can do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command to do the trick:

```
$ awk '{if($6=="\"GET")ip[$1]++; else ip[$1]+=0}END{for(elem in ip){print elem, ip[elem]}}' input.log | sort -k2nr
140.211.167.27 2
140.211.167.25 1
140.211.167.9 1
66.249.74.101 1
128.193.164.34 0
```

**Explanations:**

- `{if($6=="\"GET")ip[$1]++; else ip[$1]+=0}` on each line of the file it will check the 6th field and if it is equal to `"GET` it will increment an array for which the index is the ip; if the 6th field is not equal to `"GET` it will add 0 to the array in order to take into account the ip that have done some `POST` you can remove this logic if you do not id it.
- Then at the end of the file it will print each `ip` plus the number of `GET`
- Everything is piped to a `sort` command that will sort the output with the second field and order in reverse numerical order

Answer (score 2):

The following line is wrong:

```
name=( $(awk '{print $6}' p))
```

You should replace it with:

```
name=$(echo "$p" | awk '{print $6}')
```

You passed `p`, the variable name, to the `awk`, where a file name was expected. Also, the outer brackets were redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I try to parse the log file, for your reference:

```
#!/bin/bash
howmanyGET=0
loopcounter=0
while read line;do
    #echo "Line # $loopcounter: $line"
    ((loopcounter++))
    name=`echo $line | awk '{print $6}'`
    #name=( $(awk '{print $6}' p))
    #echo $name
    name=${name:1:3}
    echo $name
    if [ "$name" == "GET" ]
    then
        echo "yes"
        ((howmanyGET++))
    else
        echo "no"
    fi
done < transfer.log

echo "GET: $howmanyGET"
echo "loop: $loopcounter"
```

output here:

```
$ bash counter.sh 
GET
yes
GET
yes
GET
yes
GET
yes
GET
yes
POS
no
GET: 5
loop: 6
```

Hope to be helpful.